# AT commands not working while serial is working as expected for HM-10

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to use AT commands through the Arduino serial monitor, however, it seems like the HM-10 module just acts as if it is normal data being added to the custom characteristic value.

I'm using the TX and RX pins on my Arduino Mega 2560, and I'm able to transmit via bluetooth and receive values via bluetooth. However, the problem is that I want the bluetooth module to interpret the data as commands.

This is my arduino code:

```
char c=' ';
boolean NL = true;

// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Sketch:   ");   Serial.println(__FILE__);
  Serial.print("Uploaded: ");   Serial.println(__DATE__);
  Serial.println(" ");

  Serial1.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Serial1 started at 9600");
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {

  // Read from serial monitor and transmit to Bluetooth
  if (Serial.available()) {
    c = Serial.read();

    if (c!=10 & c!=13 ) {  
      Serial1.write(c);
    }

    // Echo the user input to the main window. 
    // If there is a new line print the ">" character.
    if (NL) { Serial.print("\r\n>");  NL = false; }
    Serial.write(c);
    if (c==10) { NL = true; }
  }

  // Read from Bluetooth and write to serial monitor
  if (Serial1.available()) {
    c = Serial1.read();
    Serial.write(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Using the command: AT+NAME? gives any result?

Comment: @SimeonR Not in the serial monitor, however I tried writing `Serial1.write("AT\r\n");` in setup, and it worked. Is there some way to expand the serial monitor in Arduino so that I can add `\r\n`? It seems like I bought a clone

Comment: @SimeonR AT+NAME? didnt get me anything. Just OK followed by +NAME?

Comment: At the base of the serial monitor window, next to the baud rate selection, there's a drop-down box that gives options for what to attach at the end of a string when you send it. Select newline and carriage return. See if that helps

Comment: @SimeonR Not any luck with that. Seems to only work whenever I use it in setup.

Comment: After looking at this tutorial: http://www.martyncurrey.com/hm-10-bluetooth-4ble-modules/ it seems like the code you're using might require an additional library to work. It also mentions that the HM-10 doesn't use line endings unless the firmware is upgraded to 6.05. So try using no line ending and including the library. You'll have to download it first though.

Comment: @SimeonR I've looked at it, and its not working. I also noticed now that I can't use the same commands as earlier when hardcoded in setup.  Seems random tbh.

Comment: @SimeonR The library is to use digital pins, I'm using the TX1 and RX1 pins on the Mega.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89096/discussion-between-simeon-r-and-gjert-g).